# Reading a fixed width file which is in byte and not in UTF-8

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, utf-8, mapping

I have a fixed-width file for which I have mapped the the columns based on the starting character and the length of each field.

It has always worked well until I encountered the `€` sign and noticed that the file is given to us is configured such as the starting char and length are defined in bytes.

That means since the `€` sign is encoded on three bytes, a field which has a single `€` will appear shorter by 2 characters.

An easy and incomplete workaround is when parsing the file line by line to replace `€` by `€`  . This might require to handle more characters later (such has `£`). It is quite unlikely to have many of them but since this field is unconstrained it highly likely to have an unwelcome failure some day.

Is there a better way of doing this?

```cs
using (var readFile = new StreamReader(path))
{
    var line = readFile.ReadLine();
    while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        line = line.Replace("€", "€  ");
        ///Mycode...
        var obj = new T();
        obj.AssignObjectValuesFromFixedWidthLine(line);
        ... 
        ///
    }
}
```

Comment: And this workaround would not even preserve the field if the € is not at the end.

Comment: If the row/field-length is specified in bytes, but contains UTF-8 characters, then you will have problems. The only sane thing I can imagine is to change it so row/field length is specified in a number of characters. Or use a fixed length encoding like UTF32.

Comment: It's a bloomberg file. They don't want to change their specifications which are in byte.

Comment: So, what should happen if a character happens to be split by a row/field boundary?

Comment: strings are truncated if longer than the length defined and there cannot be any eol character... but to be honest I don't know what is a row/field boundary

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a flat file parsing tool that I support. What I did to work around the issue was to read the file in ISO-8859-1 regardless of the actual code page, perform the parsing, and convert it back to the actual original code page before writing it back to the output stream.